# Yii2 override core class - class not found

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I try to extend **BaseHtml** class by follow this [tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-overview.html#customizing-helper-classes)

But is not find the BaseHtml extended class

```
namespace common\components;

class Html extends \yii\helpers\BaseHtml {
}
```

this is the error:

```
Class 'yii\helpers\BaseHtml' not found
```

Where I am wrong?

**Update**

I try to copied the Html.php file locate in Helpers and is still the same

```
<?php
/**
 * @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2008 Yii Software LLC
 * @license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/
 */
namespace yii\helpers;
/**
 * Html provides a set of static methods for generating commonly used HTML tags.
 *
 * Nearly all of the methods in this class allow setting additional html attributes for the html
 * tags they generate. You can specify, for example, `class`, `style` or `id` for an html element
 * using the `$options` parameter. See the documentation of the [[tag()]] method for more details.
 *
 * For more details and usage information on Html, see the [guide article on html helpers](guide:helper-html).
 *
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class Html extends BaseHtml
{
}
```

And now I have another problem. It not find BaseHtml fro the original class

```
vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/Html.php
```

**Solution found**

I refactored the override file and phpStorm change me the path to BaseHtml in vendor/yiisoft/yii2/classe.php

Comment: No surprise with the copied class: this would require a `use` statement. But first problem is strange. How do you use your Html class? Did you have added your class to `Yii::$classMap`?

Comment: The solution should be provided as *accepted answer*, not by marking `title` field of the question!

Comment: thanks for your time robsch, the use statment is not required and is correct like that, just extended was wrong, have to be Html and not BaseHtml. The problem was about override file and i edited my question with solution

Comment: DevDio I don't know how

Comment: Please make yourself familiar with StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

BaseHtml.php should be under /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/ folder.
If it's not there, you will need to update your vendors or try to copy file BaseHtml.php to your yii2/helpers at yii2 repo: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/b7b9c8ba40d65ec7c745ee639a8a6eb96e7aea75/framework/helpers/BaseHtml.php
Hope it helps.